# How to add new line in between in StringBuilder String while traversing throught the loop?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
//After some lines 

sbText.append(FileUtils.readFileToString(f, encoding: "utf-8"));
sbText.append("\n\n=======================\n\n");
```

The piece of content when shown contains the text....

```
Dear Name          //there is 1 \n
Bahuguna Marg,    //there is also 1 \n
Bhagwanpur,       //there is also \n\n
   
                                      Details : Claim     //there is also \n\n

Dear Rob,         //there is also \n\n

Thank you for the claim rob.       //here is 1 \n ( I want 2 \n here )

We have the block here.....................
........................      //there is also 1 \n ( I want 2 \n here )
```

How to solve this .... the String is of StringBuilder....

What I tried is I will iterate a loop in the string and If the charAt(i) contains \n and charAt(i+1) does not then i will append the \n there.....

But it is giving me the exception "StringIndexOutOfBoundException".

My piece of code is - >

```
String ns = "\n";
for(int i = 0; i < sbText.length() ; i++)
{
      if(sbText.charAt(i) == "\n" && sbText.charAt(i+1) != "\n")
        {
             sbText.append(ns,i,i+1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For any operation involving line endings, use `System.lineSeparator()`.

In the call `sbText.append(ns, i, i+1)` the start/end index applies to the parameter `ns` - so the call will always fail when `i > 0`. Also you scan past the end of `sbText` when checking `charAt(i+1)`.

Its not clear why you need to double up instances of `\n`, but you can change the logic to scan from the end backwards to ensure that you don't process same `\n` twice:

```
for(int max = sbText.length() - 1, i = max; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(sbText.charAt(i) == '\n' && (i == max || sbText.charAt(i+1) != '\n')) {
        sbText.insert(i, ns);
    }
}
```

Note that the above is not very efficient as each call to `insert` shifts all the remaining characters of StringBuilder.

If the size of your text is small you can just call:

```
String doubledNL = sbText.toString()
   .replace(System.lineSeparator(), System.lineSeparator()+System.lineSeparator());
```

Comment: Can you write the code with System.lineSeparator(). ?